# Select Option not sending Values in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, rxjs

I am building a dropdown menu in React using select/option and pulling from a mock data server side JSON object.

For some reason, my selected value is not passing, it is passing the entire object instead of the value I selected on the dropdown.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I pass the value that I selected via dropdown? I am using a props ("profile") pass from a parent component.

```
    export default function AddCapabilitiesModal({ profile, onClose }) {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [sampleTypes, setSampleTypes] = useState([])
  const [form, setForm] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (profile) {
      const values = profile
      setForm({...profile})

      const sampleTypeMap = values.map((obj, index) => obj.sampleType)
      const sampleTypeFilter = sampleTypeMap.filter(
        (type, index) => sampleTypeMap.indexOf(type) === index
      )

      setSampleTypes(sampleTypeFilter)
    
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }, [])

  const verifyInputs = () => {
    if (status === null) {
      setError(true)
    } else {
      setError(false)
      setLoading(true)
      const tableName = 'crf2e_lrn_capability_statuses'
      const body = {
        crf2e_sample_type_id: sampleTypes,
      }
      if (profile) {
        addCapabilities(tableName, body)
      }
    }
  }

 /**
   * Call windows function createItem (POST method) and send new capabilities information.
   * @param {String} tableName
   * @param {String} body
   */
  const addCapabilities = async (tableName, body) => {
    const { xhr } = await window.lrn.createItem(tableName, body)
    const newUuid = xhr.getResponseHeader('entityid')
    const newCapabilities = {
      sampleTypes
      uuid: newUuid
    }
    response(newCapabilities)
    setLoading(false)
    closeModal()
  }

       <form>
              <div className='column flex'>
                <div className='lrow filter-options group'>


                  <select className='add-cap-select'>
                    {sampleTypes.map((sampleType) => (
                      <option
                        id='sampleType'
                        key={sampleType}
                        value={sampleType}
                        onChange={(event) => onChange(event.target.value)}

                        >
                        {sampleType}
                      </option>
                    ))}
                  </select>
         </form>
```

}

**sample array with object being used**

```
[
 {
    "test": "Real-time rt-PCR",
    "agent": "Arbovirus",
    "sampleType": "Human Clinical",
    "capabilityId": "92",
    "status": "active",
    "statusID": "1",
    "uuid": "29031f1b-8bdb-ec11-a7b4-001dd80526a8"
 }
]
```

Comment: So in `onChange` you are getting the *entire object* or *array* instead of `sampleType` value? Should `onChange` be part of `select` instead of `option`? Another observation, option id is same for all items of `sampleTypes`. You can assign the unique id to each `option`.

Comment: I'm mapping through the array and then it is mapping to object which is the choices, I believe. onChange should be apart of select? and yes how would I assign the unique id? @user1672994

Comment: What does `sampleType` represent? If it's a string then you can assign like `id={sampleType}`.

Comment: so I have an array of objects. I just put a sample of what the object looks like. I then map through the array  to find unique 1/1 names which is what the agentMap + agentFilter is doing. I then use setAgents(agentFilter). What am I doing wrong here? @user1672994

Comment: As mentioned above, you should move `onChange` to select.  Also update something like`<option
                        id={sampleType.uuid}
                        key={sampleType.uuid}
                        value={sampleType.sampleType}
                        >
                        {sampleType.sampleType}
                      </option>`

Comment: You can create a sandbox sample of your problem and we can discuss over that

Comment: I'm unable to create a sandbox example because of the references needed for the program to run but when I tried your solution, I recieved this error. 'converting circular structure to json '